# VHDL Counter Error (vcom-1576)

Tags: vhdl, counter, modelsim

guys im trying to code a simple counter in VHDL but i always get this error:

```
Error: C:/Users/usrname/dir1/dir2/dir3/counter.vhd(22): near "rising_edge": (vcom-1576) expecting == or '+' or '-' or '&'.
```

Here is my Code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity counter is
port (
EXT_RST : in std_logic;
EXT_CLK : in std_logic;
EXT_LED : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
);
end counter;

architecture fast of counter is

signal count : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

begin
process(EXT_CLK, count)
  begin
    if (EXT_RST = '1') then
    count <= "00000000";
    elseif rising_edge(EXT_CLK) then
    count <= count + '1';
    end if;
 end process;
EXT_LED <= count;
end fast;
```

Has anyone an idea why im getting this error?

Comment: Hint: `elseif` is not a VHDL keyword.

Comment: when i use `else if` i get even more errors :S

Comment: Use 'elsif' instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the `elsif` Lars Asplund suggested using in his comment use type conversions for `count:

```
count <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(count) + 1);
```

or use package numeric_std_unsigned (VHDL -2008 only) instead of numeric_std.

Notice the `1` instead of `'1'` and type conversions. Those aren't needed with numeric_std_unsigned which has a "+" adding operator function with this signature:

```
[STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR,STD_ULOGIC return STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR]
```

Using package numeric_std you can also make `count` an unsigned instead of std_logic_vector and convert for the LED assignment -

```
EXT_LED <= std_logic_vector(count);
```

Also, `count` doesn't need to be in the process sensitivity list:

```
process(EXT_CLK)
```

There are no assignments in the process where the value of `count` is used except on the clock edge.

Modifying your code with the first suggestion and indenting (which helps show the sensitivity list doesn't need `count`:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity counter is
    port (
        EXT_RST : in std_logic;
        EXT_CLK : in std_logic;
        EXT_LED : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
    );
end counter;

architecture fast of counter is

signal count : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);

begin
process(EXT_CLK)
  begin
    if (EXT_RST = '1') then
        count <= "00000000";
    elsif rising_edge(EXT_CLK) then
        count <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(count) + 1);
    end if;
 end process;
    EXT_LED <= count;
end fast;
```

This analyzes, elaborates and will simulate.

This prompts the question of how `EXT_RST` and `EXT_CLK` are derived should you actually synthesize your design. If they are from buttons (particularly the clock), debounce could be necessary even with membrane switches which can age and later bounce.