# How to fix [ near "then": (vcom-1576) expecting == or '+' or '-' or '&' ] error?

Tags: vhdl

I am getting 3 same errors after compiling this code -

** Error: C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a/examples/DECODER.vhd(24): near "then": (vcom-1576) expecting == or '+' or '-' or '&'.

I have tried adding "end if;" at the end but it gives me the above errors and the following error -

** Error: C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.4a/examples/DECODER.vhd(35): VHDL Compiler exiting

```
library IEEE;

use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity DECODER is
port
(
I0: in std_logic;
I1: in std_logic;
D0: out std_logic;
D1: out std_logic;
D2: out std_logic;
D3: out std_logic
);
end DECODER;

architecture bhv of DECODER is
begin
process(I0,I1) is
begin
if (I0='0' AND I1='0') then 
  D0<= (NOT I0) AND (NOT I1);

elseif (I0='0' AND I1='1') then 
  D1<= (NOT I0) AND I1;

elseif (I0='1' AND I1='0') then 
  D2<= I0 AND (NOT I1);

elseif (I0='1' AND I1='1') then 
  D3<= I0 AND I1;
end process;
end bhv;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VHDL Counter Error (vcom-1576)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103363/vhdl-counter-error-vcom-1576)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two syntax errors.

Change `elseif` to `elsif`.

Add final `end if` just before `end process`.

Functionally to the code is odd; if synthesized it will infer latches since the output assigned is dependent on the input value, and the condition for doing an assign at each branch of the `if` is the same as the value assigned, thus the assigned value `'1'`, so the `process` is equivalent to:

```
process (I0, I1) is
begin
  if (I0 = '0' and I1 = '0') then
    D0 <= '1';
  elsif (I0 = '0' and I1 = '1') then
    D1 <= '1';
  elsif (I0 = '1' and I1 = '0') then
    D2 <= '1';
  elsif (I0 = '1' and I1 = '1') then
    D3 <= '1';
  end if;
end process;
```

With no initial or reset value for the outputs, it appears that the code will not perform any meaningful operation.